Old sci-fi movie with young blonde girl
I'm trying to identify this movie/show with a blonde girl who is special, maybe a good kind of alien or something. She reveals this in the end. She becomes sort of blue, and her face is more like a human/monkey. But it is not a children's movie; it was scary.
The movie includes men who are in suits, and they want to use the phone in a home in a desert area, but they are, I think, aliens, and they want to plug these worms or parasites in people's ears to take them over.
I know one of the men is a dark-skinned man.
I also remember the girl has powers. And she could heat a doorknob so badly that people could not enter.
Movie from the '80s or '90s.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103971/looking-for-tv-series-title-about-space-ship-hidden-on-earth?

"her face is more like a human/monkey" You mean like a human and monkey hybrid?

can you give more details? is it english spoken, american-made? does the girl have other powers? is she a kid or teen or older?
